# Is there a compiler (for GCC and/or Clang) setting that limits compiled function length?

Tags: gcc, clang, llvm, compiler-optimization

For the program I'm working on, I'd like to limit the length of each compiled function, so as to provide a hard upper-bound on the distance<sup>1</sup> required to reach a function boundary<sup>2</sup>. Is there an option in GCC or Clang (or really any compiler framework/toolchain) that will enable function splitting to do this?  Or are there limitations that I'm not aware of preventing this?

<sup>1</sup> Distance here defined as any discrete unit smaller than a function - i.e., number of instructions, number of basic blocks, number of grey hairs on Jon Skeet's head<sup>3</sup>, etc.

<sup>2</sup> I'm defining function boundary as "location where a new stack frame is pushed on to the CPU's stack". To my understanding, this happens almost exclusively when a new function is called (except occasionally for leaf functions that don't themselves call other functions).

<sup>3</sup> This is just a joke.  We all know that Jon Skeet's hair doesn't turn grey - it just garbage collects and a new hair is instantiated, good as new.

Comment: One of the limitations is that by the time it starts to make sense to talk of instruction counts, it's way too late to restructure the code (or if you prefer, the data structures on which such restructuration would make sense do not correspond to instructions that could be counted). What's a “function boundary” anyway, and what advantage is there to have gratuitously more of them than necessary to factor functionality?

Comment: @PascalCuoq I've added my definition of "function boundary" in the question.  As for why - there's a long and a short answer; the short answer is that I'm working on a dynamic run-time tool that can be engaged at any point in a program's execution but stops at the next function boundary (as defined in the question).  I'd like to provide an upper-bound as much as possible on the distance to that boundary.  The limitation you mention makes sense; would it be possible to base the limit on some other marker (i.e. number of basic blocks)?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any compiler switch, but you don't need one. The size of symbols in the text segment is easily obtained with `nm`:

```
$ nm -AP a.out|awk '$3=="T" {print $2 " " $5}'
main 000000000000005b
```

Note that this requires an unstripped executable. Many `nm` implementations provide additional options, such as decimal numbers instead of hex, which makes comparing the numbers a little easier. Turning this into a script to output functions larger than X left as an exercise :-)